# Time Since Last Purchase

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

So I have a table in a database with the following fields:

- Transaction ID
- Customer ID
- Transaction Date

I want to add an additional field to the table called

- Time since Previous Transaction for each customer

This should just be (Transaction Date A - Transaction Date B), provided the customers are the same and the table is ordered by date.

I am using mySQL (so do not have Oracle Advances PL/SQL). My table has a lot of rows.

select txn_id, cust_id, txn_date from txns;

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you want an auto-calculated field or just to initialize the values once?

Comment: I'm building an analysis table, so initialise just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is most easily done with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       datediff((select t2.TransactionDate
                 from t t2
                 where t2.CustomerId = t.CustomerId and
                       t2.TransactionDate < t.TransactionDate
                 order by t2.TransactionDate desc
                 limit 1
                ), t.TransactionDate) as daysSinceLastPurchase
from t;
```

This makes the assumption that transactions occur on different days.

If this assumption is not true and the transaction ids are in ascending order, you can use:

```
select t.*,
       datediff((select t2.TransactionDate
                 from t t2
                 where t2.CustomerId = t.CustomerId and
                       t2.TransactionId < t.TransactionId
                 order by t2.TransactionId desc
                 limit 1
                ), t.TransactionDate) as daysSinceLastPurchase
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation on the correlated sub-query theme:

```
SELECT t1.*,
    datediff(t1.tdate,
             (select MAX(t2.tdate) from trans AS t2 
              where t1.cid = t2.cid and t2.tdate < t1.tdate
             )
            ) AS 'delta'
FROM trans AS t1;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c5f2/5